# Gradle. Custom function in block plugins{}

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Can i write in my custom plugin some function like kotlin("jvm")?

```
plugins {
    java
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.71"
}
```

I want to write function myplugin("foo") in my custom plugin and then use it like

```
plugins {
    java
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.71"
    custom.plugin
    myplugin("foo")
}
```

How i can do it?

Answer (score 3):

I think that `plugins` block is some kind of a macro expression. It is parsed and precompiled using a very limited context. Probably, the magic happens somewhere in [kotlin-dsl](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/kotlin-dsl). This is probably the only way to get static accessors and extension functions from plugins to work in Kotlin. I've never seen a mention of this process in Gradle's documentation, but let me explain my thought. Probably, some smart guys from Gradle will correct me.

Let's take a look at some third-party plugin, like [Liquibase](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-gradle-plugin). It allows you to write something like this in your `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
liquibase {
    activities {
        register("name") {
            // Configure the activity here
        }
    }
}
```

Think about it: in a statically compiled language like Kotlin, in order for this syntaxt to work, there should be an extension named `liquibase` on a `Project` type (as it is the type of `this` object in every `build.gradle.kts`) available in the classpath of a Gradle's VM that executes the build script.

Indeed, if you click on it, you'll see something like:

```kotlin
fun org.gradle.api.Project.`liquibase`(configure: org.liquibase.gradle.LiquibaseExtension.() -> Unit): Unit =
    (this as org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionAware).extensions.configure("liquibase", configure)
```

But take a look at the file where it is defined. In my case it is `~/.gradle/caches/6.3/gradle-kotlin-dsl-accessors/cmljl3ridzazieb8fzn553oa8/cache/src/org/gradle/kotlin/dsl/Accessors39qcxru7gldpadn6lvh8lqs7b.kt`. It is definitelly an auto-generated file. A few levels upper in a file tree — at `~/.gradle/caches/6.3/gradle-kotlin-dsl-accessors/` in my case — there are dozens of similar directories. I guess, one by every plugin/version I've ever used with Gradle 6.3. Here is another one for the [Detekt](https://github.com/detekt/detekt) plugin:

```kotlin
fun org.gradle.api.Project.`detekt`(configure: io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.extensions.DetektExtension.() -> Unit): Unit =
    (this as org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionAware).extensions.configure("detekt", configure)
```

So, we have a bunch of `.kt` files defining all that extensions for different plugins applied to the project. That files are obviously pre-cached and precompiled and their content is available in `build.gradle.kts`. Indeed, you can find `classes` directories beside those sources.

The sources are generated based on the content of the applied plugins. It is probably a [tricky task](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/kotlin-dsl/src/main/kotlin/org/gradle/kotlin/dsl/accessors/PluginAccessorsClassPath.kt) that includes some magic, reflection and introspection. Sometimes this magic doesn't work (due too chatic Groovy nature) and then you need to use some crappy DSL from [this package](https://gradle.github.io/kotlin-dsl-docs/api/org.gradle.kotlin.dsl/kotlin.-any/index.html).

How are they generated? I see no other way, but to

1. Parse the `build.script.kts` with an embedded Kotlin compiler / lexer
2. Extract all the `plugins` sections
3. Compile them, probably against some mocks (remember that `Project` is not yet available: we're not executing the `build.gradle.kts` itself yet!)
4. Resolve the declared plugins from [Gradle Plugin repository](https://plugins.gradle.org) (with some [nuances](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugin.management.PluginManagementSpec.html) coming from `settngs.gradle.kts`)
5. Introspect plugin's artifacts
6. Generate the sources
7. Compile the sources
8. Add the resulting classes to the script's classpath

And here is the gotcha: there is a very limited context (classpath, classes, methods — call it whatever) available when compiling the `plugins` block. Actually, no plugins are yet applied! Because, you know, you're parsing the block that applies plugins. Chickens, eggs, and their problems, huh…

So, and we're getting closer to the answer on your question, to provide custom DSL in `plugins` block, you need to modify that classpath. It's not a classpath of your `build.gradle.kts`, it's the classpath of the VM that parses `build.gradle.kts`. Basically, it's Gradle's own classpath — all the classes bundled in a Gradle distribution.

So, probably the only way to provide really custom DSLs in `plugins` block is to create a custom Gradle distribution.

EDIT:

Indeed, totally forgot to test the `buildSrc`. I've created a file `PluginExtensions.kt` in it, with a content

```kotlin
inline val org.gradle.plugin.use.PluginDependenciesSpec.`jawa`: org.gradle.plugin.use.PluginDependencySpec
    get() = id("org.gradle.war") // Randomly picked

inline fun org.gradle.plugin.use.PluginDependenciesSpec.`jawa`(): org.gradle.plugin.use.PluginDependencySpec {
    return id("org.gradle.cunit") // Randomly picked
}
```

And it seems to be working:

```kotlin
plugins {
    jawa
    jawa()
}
```

However, this is only working when `PluginExtensions.kt` is in the default package. Whenever I put it into a sub-package, the extensions are not recognized, even with an import:

[image]

Magic!

Comment: sounds complicated... Gradle supported buildSrc, which means that you can modify build classpath.I think, i need to find a way to explain gradle that I do not have the source code in the buildSrc, but the already finished jar

Comment: Yes, it work with folder buildSrc, but i want create function in my custom plugin) i don't want create folder buildSrc in every project!

Comment: Then, no other way but to add that JAR to the Gradle distribution...

Comment: When i write about buildSrc i want show, what we can change build classpath. But i wan't use it.

Comment: i try to solve this problem. I create custom plugin https://github.com/Monax111/CustomDependencyManagementPlugin
1) Have class PluginDefaultVersions with version of plugin
2) Apply default props for plugin extention.
It work for project on Grovy, but with kotlin i have 
`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/tasks/KotlinCompile`
if you want, you can experiment on project https://github.com/Monax111/springApply (plugin must be push to local repo before)
may be you know workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The `kotlin` function is just a simple extension function wrapping the traditional `id` method, not hard to define:

```
fun PluginDependenciesSpec.kotlin(module: String): PluginDependencySpec =
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.$module")
```

However, this extension function is part of the standard gradle kotlin DSL API, which means it's available without any plugin. If you want to make a custom function like this available, you would need a plugin. A plugin to load your plugin. Not very practical.

I also tried using the `buildSrc` module to make an extension function like the above. But it turns out that `buildSrc` definitions aren't even available from the plugins DSL block, which has a very constrained syntax. That wouldn't have been very practical anyway, you would have needed to make a buildSrc folder for every project in which you have wanted to use the extension.

I'm not sure if this is possible at all. Try asking on https://discuss.gradle.org/.